Having external Swagger JSON along with Springdoc-generated Swagger
I'm developing a Spring application that integrates with Camunda. It exposes both Camunda and custom endpoints. I would like to keep both Swaggers inside the application, like so:


But as soon as I add this in the application.properties:
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].name=Camunda
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].url=/path/to/camunda-swagger.json

I can't see the custom documentation, as if these properties would override the default configuration.
I already tried setting the properties' index to 1, but it will lead to an error.
Binding to target [Bindable@38d308e7 type = java.util.Set<org.springdoc.core.properties.AbstractSwaggerUiConfigProperties$SwaggerUrl>, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]], bindMethod = [null]] failed:

Because it will look for the properties with index 0.

I figured out that I have to re-add the default endpoint. The main challenge was understanding the path where the .json is stored (in my case, /v3/api-docs).
Properties will look like this:
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].name=Camunda
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].url=/path/to/camunda-swagger.json

springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].name=Camunda Integration
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].url=/v3/api-docs

And now I can properly change definitions and interact with a specific Swagger.

